# Grouping Variable Based on Filter

Tags: grouping, heatmap, tableau-api

Here is my Tableau [data viz](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/logarithmic_order_quantity/Some_vs_Remaining) tab "Some_vs_Remaining"

I am trying to group following into one variable, called Group

- Atlantic
- Northwest Territories
- Nunavut
- Ontario
- Prarie
- Quebec
- West
- Yukon

Then I would like to compare Group with

- Ontario
- Prarie
- Quebec
- Yukon

Instead, I can only create group without Ontario, Prarie, Quebec, and Yukon, which defeats the purpose of comparing some regions with total number of regions.

Below I have 'Some vs Remaining'. I wish to create 'All vs Remaining', Please help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimensions partition the data by definition, so you can't use a dimension to divide your data into overlapping categories.

You can define a set of measures that filter to data of interest such as, atlantic_ontario_sales =

```
floor(log(sum(if [Region] = "Atlantic" or [Region] = "Ontario" then [Sales] end)))
```

The inner if will "return" null for non-matching data rows. Since aggregation functions like sum() ignore nulls, the effect is to aggregate only the data that 
matches your criteria.

Make one of these for each of your columns above, and then put Measure Names on the Column shelf and place the measures you want on the Measure Values shelf.

There is one hitch though, you can't put Measure Values on the Shape Shelf, so you'll have to use another mark type such as circle or square. You can use Measure Values on Size and Color.